# Performance debugging single thread applications with multi thread processors

Tags: multithreading, performance

This is new to me so here goes.

My employer uses  single thread core line of business application.

Our core LOB VM is running Windows Server 2012 Datacentre 64bit with SQL Server 2016 Standard 64bit.  It has 4 logical cores assigned from Intel Xeon E5-2630 v4 CPU.  This is well within the system requirements stated on the website which does not state it is a single thread application.

I have read that you could essentially say a logical core is the same as a thread.

As simply as possible, is this the case?

If so, will a single thread application at the application layer by default, not make best use of those logical cores or threads?

We have encountered some performance issues and we have already had a network audit carried out to determine if there are any bottlenecks.  This audit has confirmed that the servers, network and client machines are not under any heavy load.  All client machines are i5 deployments with 8GB RAM and a mix of mechanical and SSD hard drives.

I can provide more information if needed

Comment: If this question has already been answered elsewhere or would be st placed at another site please accept my apologies.  I did have a look but only found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168856/single-thread-to-multi-threaded-application

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer which the constructive person who kindly marked me -1 must have known :)